# Can't launch android app from eclipse on my Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to run a simple android app on my Samsung Galaxy S4 phone (the default hello world app). When I try to launch the app from eclipse my phone is in the list of options but its target is unknown and its state is unknown. So it is not possible to press okey and launch the application.

The thing is that this has worked before (launching my apps from eclipse on my phone) so I don't know why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all the help guys. I restarted my phone and now I got the question to accept that the app could be run on my phone and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to activate the [developer mode](http://blog.immersion.com/2013/05/developer-options-galaxy-s4/). Then, once you connect your phone to the pc, it may ask for permission to execute the app: you grant it and now instead of unknown you should get the model of the phone or somethign similar (don't remember exactly right now).

Comment: The developer mode is already activated. My phone never asks for permission to execute the app.

Answer (score 0):

If it has worked before, you should unplug your phone, close Eclipse, stop adb process then reconnect the phone and start Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Windows => Open Perspective => DDMS

And reset adb there and try it again

[image]

Comment: I can't restart the adb. If I click on the my device like that. No menu appears.

Comment: Unplug ur device, go to DDMS, and click on the down arrow on the top of the menu in the pic. U will see reset adb. Click it and then plug ur device again. See if it works